# Unable to implement custom keyboard using Android Fragment - Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm attempting to implement a custom keyboard using the following example:

http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm

However instead of implementing it an Activity as described in the article - I'm attempting to implement it in a fragment and I can't seem to get it to work without throwing a NPE.

I'm not sure exactly what I've done wrong in this instance - but any suggestions/input is greatly appreciated.

```
05-12 09:48:10.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3664): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 09:48:10.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3664): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-12 09:48:10.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3664):     at com.example.project.CustomKeyboard.<init>(CustomKeyboard.java:111)
05-12 09:48:10.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3664):     at com.example.project.LoginDialog.onCreateDialog(LoginDialog.java:64)
05-12 09:48:10.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3664):     at android.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:398)
05-12 09:48:10.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3664):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
05-12 09:48:10.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3664):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
05-12 09:48:10.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3664):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
05-12 09:48:10.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3664):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
05-12 09:48:10.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3664):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
05-12 09:48:10.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3664):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-12 09:48:10.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3664):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-12 09:48:10.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3664):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-12 09:48:10.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3664):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-12 09:48:10.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3664):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 09:48:10.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3664):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-12 09:48:10.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3664):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-12 09:48:10.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3664):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-12 09:48:10.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3664):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

CustomKeyboard.java:111
```

is

```
mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(mHostActivity, layoutid));


LoginDialog.java:64
```

is

```
mCustomKeyboard= new CustomKeyboard(this, R.id.keyboardview, R.xml.hexkbd );
```

### CustomKeyboard.java

```
public CustomKeyboard(LoginDialog loginDialog, int viewid, int layoutid) {
    mHostActivity= loginDialog.getActivity();
    mKeyboardView= (KeyboardView)mHostActivity.findViewById(viewid);
    mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(mHostActivity, layoutid));
    mKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false); // NOTE Do not show the preview balloons
    mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(mOnKeyboardActionListener);
    // Hide the standard keyboard initially
    mHostActivity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
}
```

### LoginDialog.java

```
 public class LoginDialog extends DialogFragment implements ActionCompletedListener{
    private SingletonVariables variables;

    private View view;
    private TextView error;
    private String whichActivity = "";
    CustomKeyboard mCustomKeyboard;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(),R.style.HoloDarkDialog));
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        variables = SingletonVariables.getInstance();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, null);
        EditText userEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.loginUserIdEditText);
        mCustomKeyboard= new CustomKeyboard(this, R.id.keyboardview, R.xml.hexkbd );
        mCustomKeyboard.registerEditText(R.id.loginUserIdEditText); 
                mCustomKeyboard.registerEditText(R.id.loginPasswordEditText); 
        if(variables.login.sessionPassword != null) {
            userEditText.setText(variables.login.sessionUser);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was just having the same problem, and I think I got it. Try adding a View variable to the CustomKeyboard class like so:

```
private View mRootView;
```

Then modify the constructor:

```
 public CustomKeyboard(Activity host, View rootView, int viewid, int layoutid) {
    mHostActivity= host;
    mRootView = rootView;
    mKeyboardView= (KeyboardView)mRootView.findViewById(viewid);
    mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(mHostActivity, layoutid));
    mKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false); // NOTE Do not show the preview balloons
    mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(mOnKeyboardActionListener);
    mHostActivity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

}
```

Modify the registerEditText() so that:

```
EditText edittext= (EditText)mHostActivity.findViewById(resid);
```

Becomes:

```
EditText edittext= (EditText)mRootView.findViewById(resid);
```

Then change the call in your DialogFragment onCreateDialog() like so:

```
    @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(),R.style.HoloDarkDialog));
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    variables = SingletonVariables.getInstance();
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, null);
    EditText userEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.loginUserIdEditText);
    mCustomKeyboard= new CustomKeyboard(getActivity() , view , R.id.keyboardview, R.xml.hexkbd );
    mCustomKeyboard.registerEditText(R.id.loginUserIdEditText); 
    mCustomKeyboard.registerEditText(R.id.loginPasswordEditText); 
    if(variables.login.sessionPassword != null) {
    userEditText.setText(variables.login.sessionUser);
    }
```

I hope this helps somebody (I imagine OP has already figured something out) but this is the first time I have had anything to contribute and I am kind of excited.

Comment: Is the KeyboardView in Activity layout or in Fragment layout?

Comment: Fragment layout

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `LoginDialog` is not attached to any `Activity` when you instantiate the `CustomKeyboard` and therefore :

```
loginDialog.getActivity() is null
```

There is a callback [`onAttach`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach%28android.app.Activity%29) that you can use to instantiate your CustomKeyboard since at this point the dialog is attached to an Activity

---

Try this:

```
public void onAttach(Activity hostActivity) {
    super.onAttach(hostActivity);

    mCustromKeyboard = new CustomKeyboard(activity, R.id.keyboardview, R.xml.hexkbd ));
    mCustromKeyboard.registerEditText(R.id.loginUserIdEditText); 
    mCustromKeyboard.registerEditText(R.id.loginPasswordEditText); 
}
```

Comment: The code in your link don't make sense. Can you explain what you are trying to do with this code ?

Comment: instantiate a CustomKeyboard using onAttach as you mentioned :(